# How can we make a div visible over another div while hover

Tags: css, wordpress

How can we make a div visible over another div  while hover . While hover the div is hiding .

Please check it [here](http://development.hostroom.in/australiancapitalcollege/) - the DOWNLOAD button in the footer section - just above the footer widget .

Please help me to make that download hover drop down visible while hover

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your code?  Posting a link to an offsite resource which may change in the future doesn't help the community.

Comment: Dear Justin it is a wordpress site ..

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific and clear when you're wording your question to the community. First, it is not clear to me what your problem is: in your example, the hover menu seems to be working. What divs should be visible during hover and what divs should be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this.

```
/* display */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


/* hide */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
```